# Why can't I see previous edits when I click 'edit' on a question?

Tags: discussion, support

Is this deliberate?

I don't see any previous edits when I click on the edit button. This has been the case for the last few days.

Why?

**edit**

To be more precise, when I have clicked on edit in Phil.SE, I can usually see all the revisions that an edit has incurred and then rollback if I so chose. Does this mean simply I haven't accrued enough points for that particular privilege? If so, how many points does one need.

Comment: For the edit: If that's what you are asking then the rollback is there in the edit history. For example I did the same with your post and I have less reputation than yours. So you have the privilege to do the rollback.

Answer (score 2):

Edit button is not for the purpose of seeing the edit history of a question/answer. For seeing the edit history of the question click on the word "edited" which sits above the user card. See the following image:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: ....Or the timeline button up there below the question score.